# Why app does crash when trying to buy in App Store, but everything works in the sandbox (iOS)?

Tags: ios, swift, in-app-purchase, app-store

Good day everyone!

The problem is the following: when I test the application in the sandbox, everything works fine. And the application appears in App Store and crashes when you try to buy. The purchase is not consumable.

Some facts that may lead to the right thought:

- Crash occurs after the lines:
  let payment = SKPayment (product: subscription.product);
  SKPaymentQueue.default().Add(payment)
- The application does not crash "instantly", but after ~ 1 second, which means that it crashes after some response from the server
- The window with the input of the password, login, confirmation of the purchase does not appear on the screen. Crash happens before that.
- This app has been posted to App Store as an update of the old one. It was created in a new project, in which the bundle id was changed to the bundle id of the old application.
- All purchases in itunesconnect approved by the moderator, they are displayed in App Store.

```
class BillingManager: NSObject {

    static let sessionIdSetNotification = Notification.Name("SubscriptionServiceSessionIdSetNotification")
    static let optionsLoadedNotification = Notification.Name("SubscriptionServiceOptionsLoadedNotification")
    static let restoreSuccessfulNotification = Notification.Name("SubscriptionServiceRestoreSuccessfulNotification")
    static let purchaseSuccessfulNotification = Notification.Name("SubscriptionServiceRestoreSuccessfulNotification")

    private override init() { }
    private static var instance: BillingManager?

    /** создает 1 объект или возвращает текущий (синглтон) */
    static func shared() -> BillingManager {
        if instance == nil {
            instance = BillingManager()
        }
        return instance!
    }

    var isPro: Bool {

        /** Здесь проверяем дату подписки по UserDefaults */

        var subscriptionAccess = false


        if let purchase = UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "purchaseDate") {
            if let expires = UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "expiresDate") {
                if let purchaseDate = dateFormatter.date(from: purchase), let expiresDate = dateFormatter.date(from: expires) {

                    subscriptionAccess = (purchaseDate...expiresDate).contains(Date())

                }
            }
        }

        return (currentSubscription != nil) || subscriptionAccess || UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: "forever.subscription")
    }

    var hasReceiptData: Bool {
        return loadReceipt() != nil
    }

    var currentSessionId: String? {
        didSet {
            NotificationCenter.default.post(name: BillingManager.sessionIdSetNotification, object: currentSessionId)
        }
    }

    var currentSubscription: PaidSubscription?

    var options: [Subscription]? {
        didSet {
            NotificationCenter.default.post(name: BillingManager.optionsLoadedNotification, object: options)
        }
    }

    func loadSubscriptionOptions() {
        let productIDs = Set([InAppType.month.rawValue,
                              InAppType.halfYear.rawValue,
                              InAppType.year.rawValue,
                              InAppType.forever.rawValue,
                              InAppType.discountedForever.rawValue])

        let request = SKProductsRequest(productIdentifiers: productIDs)
        request.delegate = self
        request.start()
    }

    func purchase(subscription: Subscription) {
        let payment = SKPayment(product: subscription.product)
        SKPaymentQueue.default().add(payment)
    }

    func restorePurchases() {
        SKPaymentQueue.default().restoreCompletedTransactions()
    }

    func uploadReceipt(completion: ((_ success: Bool) -> Void)? = nil) {

        if let receiptData = loadReceipt() {
            Service.shared.upload(receipt: receiptData) { [weak self] (result) in
                guard let strongSelf = self else { return }
                switch result {
                case .success(let result):
                    strongSelf.currentSessionId = result.sessionId
                    strongSelf.currentSubscription = result.currentSubscription
                    completion?(true)
                case .failure(let error):
                    print(" Receipt Upload Failed: \(error)")
                    completion?(false)
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private func loadReceipt() -> Data? {
        guard let url = Bundle.main.appStoreReceiptURL else {
            return nil
        }

        do {
            let data = try Data(contentsOf: url)
            return data
        } catch {
            print("Error loading receipt data: \(error.localizedDescription)")
            return nil
        }
    }

}


extension BillingManager: SKProductsRequestDelegate {
    func productsRequest(_ request: SKProductsRequest, didReceive response: SKProductsResponse) {
        options = response.products.map { Subscription(product: $0) }.sorted(by: { (left, right) -> Bool in
            left.product.price < right.product.price
        })

    }

    func request(_ request: SKRequest, didFailWithError error: Error) {
        if request is SKProductsRequest {
            print("Subscription Options Failed Loading: \(error.localizedDescription)")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You have an app in the appstore in which the `expiresDate` is stored in the user defaults??!??!?!!!??!!

Comment: What happened? Yes

Comment: You aware of the fact anyone can change those values?

Comment: Where is your payment queue observer added?  Can you show its code. Can you run the app on your own device and get the crash log or exception message from the console?

Comment: @Paulw11 where can I send you code? And now I have crash log, but I can't to understand, where is mistake

Comment: Edit your question to show the code.  What is the exception message from the crashlog?  You may need to symbolicate it to identify the crashing line

Comment: @paulw11 Exception Type:  EXC_BREAKPOINT (SIGTRAP)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000001, 0x0000000104f9226c
Termination Signal: Trace/BPT trap: 5
Termination Reason: Namespace SIGNAL, Code 0x5
Terminating Process: exc handler [766]

How can I symbolicate? Now I have lines like "0x104f28000 + 434796"

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/technotes/tn2151/_index.html